# Unity CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have been trying to get Unity to build for Android and have come across this error (I am running on Mac, if that makes any difference):

```
Error building Player: CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package     resources. See the Console for details.
/Users/garyjohnston/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/23.0.2/aapt package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "/Users/garyjohnston/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_

stderr[
AndroidManifest.xml:23: Tag <provider> attribute authorities hasinvalid character '|'.
]
stdout[
Configurations:
 (default)
 xhdpi-v4

Files:
  drawable/app_banner.png
Src: (xhdpi-v4) res/drawable-xhdpi/app_banner.png
  drawable/app_icon.png
Src: () res/drawable/app_icon.png
  values/strings.xml
Src: () res/values/strings.xml
  AndroidManifest.xml
Src: () AndroidManifest.xml

Resource Dirs:
  Type drawable
drawable/app_banner.png
  Src: (xhdpi-v4) res/drawable-xhdpi/app_banner.png
drawable/app_icon.png
  Src: () res/drawable/app_icon.png
  Type values
values/strings.xml
  Src: () res/values/strings.xml
Including resources from package: /Users/garyjohnston/Library/Android/sdk/platforms/android-23/android.jar
applyFileOverlay for drawable
applyFileOverlay for layout
applyFileOverlay for anim
applyFileOverlay for animator
applyFileOverlay for interpolator
applyFileOverlay for transition
applyFileOverlay for xml
applyFileOverlay for raw
applyFileOverlay for color
applyFileOverlay for menu
applyFileOverlay for mipmap
Processing image: res/drawable-xhdpi/app_banner.png
Processing image: res/drawable/app_icon.png
(processed image res/drawable/app_icon.png: 94% size of source)
(processed image res/drawable-xhdpi/app_banner.png: 93% size of source)
(new resource id app_banner from xhdpi-v4/drawable/app_banner.png #generated)
(new resource id app_icon from drawable/app_icon.png #generated)
]
```

[image]

I have tried most of the answers I have found online and, so far, nothing has worked. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your Android manifest has an invalid character '|'. Please check that your manifest file is syntactically correct.

I hope that helps!

EDIT:
I will be able to help point the error more specifically if you can share your manifest file please.

Comment: When I went to copy the code from the manifest to share, I found some stuff from old plugins that had not been removed and it works now. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: I'm glad you got it to work :) It would be really appreciated if you could select this response as the answer or upvote it please. Thanks and good luck! @PlacusBrutus